# how to pass the data to first tab of the tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

How to pass the data to first tab of tabbar controller from a table view .I have didSelectRowAt indexPath method as follow

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let storybaord=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
         ///App crash /  let tabBar=storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! UITabBarController
            let DVC = tabBar.viewControllers?[0] as! NewsViewController
            tabBar.selectedIndex = 0
            DVC.getImage=sneakersnews[indexPath.row].image
            DVC.getNews=sneakersnews[indexPath.row].news
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBar, animated: true)

        }
```

I want to pass image and news from view controller to connected first tab of tabbar controller but the app crash while selecting a row .How to pass data from view controller to first tab of tab bar controller ? you can download the project from this link.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rXIyN7uBAB4hJT28H_eAgAEGEUOGRfIa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is the identifier correct?

Comment: You did not set Storyboard Id to UITabBarController.

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain what's wrong with your project.

Answer (score 3):

Check wether your first tab is not of type `NewsViewController`. I think it would be `UINavigationController`. So try below:

```
 let NVC = tabBar.viewControllers?[0] as! UINavigationController
 let VC = NVC.viewControllers[0] as! NewsViewController
 VC.getImage=sneakersnews[indexPath.row].image
 VC.getNews=sneakersnews[indexPath.row].news
```

Comment: The program crash at first line without any error description  .      let NVC = tabBar.viewControllers?[0] as! UINavigationController.

Answer (score 1):

The view controller with `tabBar` storyboard ID is not the tab bar controller, you have to set storyboard IDs properly for that code to work.
First, in the storyboards set the `tabBarController` id to the `UITabBarController` (see image below):

[image]

Then, change the crashing code to:

```
let tabBar=storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController") as! UITabBarController
```

Or use the old ID `tabBar` - but then you will have to first change it in the news view controller (the one with the sneaker image in the picture I uploaded).

The problem is trivial anyway -- you want to instantiate the `UITabBarController` from the storyboard, but currently your storyboard does not associate it with the `tabBar` ID, but it associates that ID with a different controller.

**EDIT**

Altogether, the project is super messy. Check some apple developer guidelines for naming and other advices.

The problem here is that you are mixing navigation using segues (there is a segue for tapping the cell to open a tab bar) and programmatic navigation (the `tableView`'s `didSelectRowAt` method where you are trying to set the data).

The view that gets presented that misses the image and title is the result of the segue. But you are not setting the data for segue, which results in your problem.

The programmatic code that you showed us does get executed, but is useless. The `DiscoveryNewsViewController` that should pop up the detail view is not embedded in `UINavigationController`. Therefore the following line:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBar, animated: true)
```

Is not executed. In your case `self.navigationController` contains nil, thus the line will not get executed and the detail view with image and title will not get presented.

You have two options now.

**OPTION 1 - programmatic approach**

Delete the segue. In the Main storyboard click on the segue between `DiscoveryNewsViewController` and `UITabBarController` and press delete. See the following image:

[image]

Then use following `didSelectRowAt` implementation in `DiscoveryNewsViewController` to present the detail:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storybaord=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBar=storybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController") as! UITabBarController
    let DVC = tabBar.viewControllers?[0] as! NewsViewController
    tabBar.selectedIndex = 0

    DVC.getImage=self.sneakersnews[indexPath.row].image
    DVC.getNews=self.sneakersnews[indexPath.row].news

    self.present(tabBar, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Notice that I don't use `self.navigationController?.pushViewController` but rather `self.present`.

Also modify `NewsViewController` to this:

```
class NewsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var newsTitle: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var NewsImage: UIImageView!

    var getNews=String() {
        didSet {
            newsTitle.text = getNews
        }
    }

    var getImage=UIImage() {
        didSet {
            NewsImage.image = getImage
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Using `didSet` on properties will set image and title properly. It seems that `viewDidLoad` gets called before you set the image and title in the `didSelectRowAt`.

**OPTION 2 - storyboards approach**

Keep the segue. Set its identifier to `showDetailSegue` (see following image):

[image]

Then delete the `didSelectRowAt` from `DiscoveryNewsViewController`.

Instead of that use `prepare(for:sender:)` to configure the `NewsViewController` before it is presented:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetailSegue",
        let tabBar = segue.destination as? UITabBarController,
        let DVC = tabBar.viewControllers?[0] as? NewsViewController,
        let selectedRow = DiscoveryNewsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

        tabBar.selectedIndex = 0

        DVC.getImage=self.sneakersnews[selectedRow.row].image
        DVC.getNews=self.sneakersnews[selectedRow.row].news
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm using

```
segue.identifier == "showDetailSegue"
```

in the test to make sure that the segue we are handling is really the one we want to handle. In your project there is only this segue, so it is not so important, but in a larger project it is a good practice to name your segues.

Comment: It is not displaying news title and image that i am passing from view controller to ist tab of tabbar controller ?That's the problem

Comment: @ajadka did my updated answer help? if so, can you accept it please?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `Main.storyboard` then click on `NewsViewController` and remove it's Storyboard ID as shown in below image:

[image]

Then assign `Storyboard ID` to your `UITabBarController` as shown in below image:

[image]

Comment: It is not displaying news title and image that i am passing from view controller to ist tab of tabbar controller ?That's the problem